# Does a task throwing an exception (no wait, no Exception accessed) crash the program?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, task-parallel-library

Did the following program really crash when running under the framework 4.0? It doesn't when it runs under 4.5 or later, consistent with [this MSDN blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/09/28/task-exception-handling-in-net-4-5.aspx), although this [relevant article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997415%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) doesn't appear to have been updated and still says the code should throw ("the exception is escalated according to the .NET exception policy").

The reason that I'm asking is that in my real world application I have a number of Tasks which may throw an exception in order to signal failure and are never actually waited for. We still deploy on Windows XP machines (don't ask) [which support only Framework 4.0.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/p/dotnet45xp.aspx) We have not received bug reports from them, but because the issue is related to garbage collection the exceptions may only bubble up when the program is running for a long time or when there is a demand for more memory from somewhere else.

(For completeness, the design is that the Tasks log and clean up locally and then re-throw just in order to fail, which is recognized by a continuation.) For the same reason which inspired the change in behavior between the 4.0 and 4.5 versions of the framework, which are discussed by Stephen Toub in the [blog article mentioned above](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/09/28/task-exception-handling-in-net-4-5.aspx), it would be hard for me to wait for (or access the Exception property of) all tasks which may throw. (I cannot help but think of it as a theological puzzle -- if there is a devil who claims the sould of all sinners, who will eventually claim *his* soul? The reverse of "who started the first program?")

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TaskExceptions
{
    class TaskWithDtor: Task
    {
        public TaskWithDtor(Action a) : base(a) { }

        ~TaskWithDtor() 
        { 
            Console.WriteLine("~TaskWithDtor executing"); 
            // now calls Task's destructor implicitly
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var twd = new TaskWithDtor(() => 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Task executing, now going to throw ...");
                throw new Exception("Thrown by task");
            });

            twd.RunSynchronously(); // make sure it's done ...

            // ... but do no wait
        }
    }
}
```

Sample output when run in VS 2013, compiled (and probably run) against Framework 4.6.1:

```
Task executing, now going to throw ...
~TaskWithDtor executing
```

Edit: As suggested in the link provided by i3arnon in a comment I included the element

```
<runtime> 
      <ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions enabled="true"/> 
</runtime>
```

in my application's app.config, but it didn't change the behavior (which is that the program does not throw an exception when running under 4.5 or later -- I actually installed Framework version 4.6.1). What am I missing?

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: @i3arnon The first sentence of my post is "Did the following program really crash when running under the framework 4.0?". It doesn't when run under a later version, but I have no way of verifying behavior under 4.0.

Comment: Well then, yes (given enough time). And you can re-enable the behavior with the `ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions` flag.

Comment: @i3arnon Since you are from MS, this is also the first time I encountered MSDN documentation which is factually wrong, which is why I was unsure about everything.

Comment: @i3arnon And concerning the flag: I read about it and don't really know where to put it. My program has an app.config which has a root element <configuration>, but the flag has no effect there (shouldn't it be somewhere in a global config file for the Framework?).

Comment: What I do is unrelated. I just use the framework. But this isn't really the documentation. It's an article that was correct when it came out. It also doesn't list any new versions at the top. In any case, there's no better documentation than the word of Stephen Toub.

Comment: If you want the current documentation you can get it here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.unobservedtaskexception(v=vs.110).aspx